# Convert file path to URI object emf.common.util.URI

Tags: java, eclipse, uri, filepath, emf

I need a solution to convert file path to EMF URI, not a Java URI.

I tried with this:

```
org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI ur = org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.createURI(URI.createURI(file.getPath()).toString());
```

...but  I get this exception:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c appears .
```

Is there another solution?

Comment: emf URI can point to files? What protocol is in `URI.createURI(file.getPath())`?

Answer (score 1):

In EMF, `URI` classe comes with a lot of static methods to help you create your URI. In your specific case, try `URI.createFileURI(...)` instead of `URI.createURI(...)`

```
URI fileURI = URI.createFileURI(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Look here for details about the method: http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.4.3/org/eclipse/emf/common/util/URI.html#createFileURI(java.lang.String)

Comment: thank you .I solved the problem with:    Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI(file.toURI().toString()));